# Any good algorithm to find a "best" path as defined below in a weighted graph?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, graph

Currently I'm learning graph theory, during which I was stuck in the following graph-related problem. Let's start with an example. This may sound like a pure math problem.

Eg: A weighted graph to be implemented:

[image]

A simplified graph is shown above (it was extracted from a more complex network).

There are 5 simple paths, 14 edges with their respective weights, and 11 nodes (the blue ones in different paths can be the same, but in a single path the nodes are totally different). I'm trying to find the best path between node ***s*** and node ***t*** (both colored as black) which satisfies the following conditions:

1. the path should be as **short** as possible;
2. the weights of each edge along the path should be as **large** as possible.

Or I can even rank all the simple paths based on some methods?

More specifically, let's consider the nodes to be the ***users*** in a social network, and the edges the ***associations between each pair of users***. The weights are **in proportion to** the **reliability of association** (10 is the most reliable one while 1 is the least).

So, is there a good way to define and calculate the weights of indirect associations (the paths between node ***s*** and node ***t*** in the example)? As we know the more connections (edges) a single path has between ***s*** and ***t***, the reliability of it tends to decline; moreover, the decrease in the reliability of each connection of this single path will also lead to the decline in its reliability. That's why the aforementioned conditions desire a shorter path, and larger weights in each edge of the path.

Thank you for your time, guys!

Comment: Isn't this simply Dijkstra with reversed order relation?

Comment: @Maikel It's a little unclear because I don't see a defined precedence between the priorities, but you can't just invert Djikstra's algorithm and suddenly find longest paths. (Djikstra's logic relies upon paths only getting "worse" as you add more edges to them; if exploring unseen edges can give a better result, Djikstra fails.)

Comment: Ah, and since the weight added by future paths can make another path better it fails. I see.

Comment: Please clarify - 1) is the length of the path (to be minimized) the number of edges (blue nodes +1) in the path?  2) Do you mean the sum of the weights along the path should be maximized?  If so, how much is a "node" worth?  For example, which is "better," a path that has only 2 segments and total weight of 15, or a path that has 4 segments and a total weight of 36?  Perhaps you want to maximize the **average** segment weight?  In the example, the first path has an average weight of 7.5 while the 2nd has an average of 9, so the 2nd would be "better."

Comment: @amdn 1)Yes. 2)Not really. The sum of the weights are supposed to be larger considering the second condition, but the situation that the sum of the weights reaches maximum does not definitely indicate a best path in that it's likely that the first condition cannot be satisfied. Let me put in another way. I've updated it in the main post. You can check it. Thanks. : )

Comment: So the more crucial criterion is the path being the shortest. As a secondary criterion, among the shortest paths with length, say, d we are to pick the one with the largest individual edges. If what I describe is correct, then I will need some extra clarification on how you define the secondary condition.

Comment: Is it sufficient among shortest paths p and q, that the better option would be p if the smallest edge of p has a greater cost than smallest edge of q? Or do you require element-wise comparison as well? For instance if p had edges 5,6,7 and q had edges 1, 2, 7, 8 which would be the better option for you? Is it q, and why so? In other words, specifically what do you consider when comparing p & q? The # of edges involved, the cheapest edges of each, the most expensive edges them, etc.?

Comment: @ilim Actually, the best path may not be the shortest, either. In an extreme case, I have Path A with **Weights[10,10,10]** and Path B with **Weights[1,1]**. Path A is apparently more desirable. That's where I'm flummoxed. The best path can be neither the shortest nor the one with largest sum of weights. As for the secondary condition, a lot of definitions can be given to "as large as possible". It can be defined as Top _**P%**_ of all the weights, and the figure of _**P**_ matters. If _**P**_ is too small, we will find no path.

Comment: @Hendrik You seem to be vaguely describing a partial ordering of sorts, but the problem definition does not include any indications as to how we are supposed to pick the most favorable of the paths that can not be compared. Any chance you could mention where you encountered this problem or how you plan to make use of the solution to it?

Comment: @Hendrik Also, could you rate how favorable each path is in the visual you provided in your question?

Comment: @ilim The example of social network is exactly the origin of the problem. I cannot rate all the paths, but I'd like to rate Path [9, 9, 9] as the most reliable one and Path [10, 9, 10, 7] as the least reliable one, which is in accord with the results based on the method proposed by Mr. amdn. More over, Path [8, 7] is more reliable than Path [6, 9].

Comment: @Hendrik my answer is in accordance with your preferences as well. If you enumerate the paths from top to bottom with numbers 1 to 5, the formula I wrote, with the sample constants I provided,would rate the reliability of the paths as 5>3>1>2>4, **if** you pick c_3 as the minimum edge along the path.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the problem defines only vaguely how favorable each possible path is, an answer to this question should first define such an ordering.

Based on your problem definition, more specifically from your example about the social network relations, I think we can derive the factors in favor and against how favorable a path is.

We know that each edge is in favor of the *reliability* of the path in an amount that is directly proportional to its cost, or value, in this case. Intuitively, there seems to be a factor in favor of the reliability of the path which is directly proportional to the average cost of the edges on it. You also mentioned the length to be a second factor that affects things, but this time in the other direction. (i.e. against the reliability of a path)

Considering those two factors, a formula such as the following may be derived, and used to rank the reliability of each path.

[image]

As you can observe, there is a summation expression where **c<sub>e<sub>i</sub></sub>** represents the cost of each edge **e<sub>i</sub>** on the path. **n** indicates the number of edges on the path. The entire summation divided by n is essentially the first factor I mentioned above. (i.e. the average cost of edges on the path) while the second n in the expression n<sup>2</sup> in the denominator is the second factor, the length of the path, which is against the reliability of an edge.

I also introduced 3 constants so that you can update this formula based on how you plan to make use of it. C<sub>2</sub> indicates an extra factor in favor how how effective the length of the path is in decreasing the reliability of the entire path. Similarly, C<sub>1</sub> is a factor indicating how effective an increased average of edge costs is in making that path more reliable. And finally, C<sub>3</sub> can be an optional factor which can be equal to either the minimum or the maximum edge cost on the path.

While C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> are relatively more intuitive to understand, here's an example case where C<sub>3</sub> may come in handy. Suppose you have paths A and B with edge costs [3, 7, 8] and [5, 6, 7], respectively. As their path length and sum of the edge costs are the same, it is not possible to identify which is the more favorable path here. This is why we need a factor such as C<sub>3</sub> in this case, and based on your need you can consider it to be equal to the minimum edge or the maximum edge for each path. If your problem definition chooses the former and assigns C<sub>3</sub> the minimum edge cost of each path, then path B is considered the better as its minimum edge cost is higher. If the latter is chosen, however, path A is more favorable.

I am aware of the fact that not defining the constants in my answer may, in a way, make one feel that the answer is incomplete. I believe an assignment as given below should work for the time being.

```
C1 = 1
C2 = 1
C3 = min(cei)
```

Still, I believe different variations of this problem may require different values for these constants, which is why I refrain from stating that these values would hold for all variations of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your posting. I think most of the parts are feasible expect one issue regarding the large enough costs of each edge. I'd like to introduce **variance**. If each edge should be large enough, the variance of the costs in a single path should be smaller. Thus in your example, Path B with edge costs[5, 6, 7] is preferred.

Comment: I think picking C_3 as the minimal edge along the path would help you achieve that, as you already kinda take into account the range of edge costs when you take their average as a factor. But a potentially better option could be usin something like 1/(max-min) for each path as its C_3.

Comment: That's feasible I think. :) Anyway, thanks for your method and I'll try both of the 2 methods in a more complex network.

Comment: @Hendrik Once you try them, make sure to come back to this question and select the answer which worked best for you as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is essentially a reliability block diagram [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_block_diagram).

> A reliability block diagram (RBD) is a diagrammatic method for showing
>   how component reliability contributes to the success or failure of a
>   complex system. RBD is also known as a dependence diagram (DD).

According to [reliawiki.org](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/RBDs_and_Analytical_System_Reliability#Effect_of_Component_Reliability_in_a_Series_System), a wiki specialized in reliability theory:

> ... for a pure series system, the system reliability is
>   equal to the product of the reliabilities of its constituent
>   components.
> <sub>[reliawiki.org](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/RBDs_and_Analytical_System_Reliability#Effect_of_Component_Reliability_in_a_Series_System)</sub>

The OP gave examples in the comments of two paths with equal number of edges and equal sum of the weights/reliability

> **Path [8, 7]** is more reliable than **Path [6, 9]**

The path in a social network is a chain of dependency, each edge represents an association between two people - the weight indicates how reliable that association is.  A chain is only as reliable as the weakest link, that's why in the example **Path [6, 9]** is less reliable than **Path [8, 7]**, it has a weaker link - an edge with reliability 6, which puts an upper bound on the reliability of the path/chain.  That's why the formula indicated by reliawiki.org for a chain (series system) is the *product* of the individual reliabilities, each factor is a reliability estimate, R, such that 0 <= R < 1, adding another segment can only decrease the final product and the lower the reliability R is, the lower the upper bound on the final product.

> **Effect of Component Reliability in a Series System--**
>   In a series configuration, the component with the least reliability
>   has the biggest effect on the system's reliability. There is a saying
>   that a chain is only as strong as its weakest link. This is a good
>   example of the effect of a component in a series system. In a chain,
>   all the rings are in series and if any of the rings break, the system
>   fails. In addition, the weakest link in the chain is the one that will
>   break first. The weakest link dictates the strength of the chain in
>   the same way that the weakest component/subsystem dictates the
>   reliability of a series system. As a result, the reliability of a
>   series system is always less than the reliability of the least
>   reliable component.
>   [image: weakest link in a chain]
> <sub>[reliawiki.org](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/RBDs_and_Analytical_System_Reliability#Effect_of_Component_Reliability_in_a_Series_System)</sub>

Reliability is expressed as a number between 0 (completely unreliable) to 1 (completely reliable).

A first approximation is to say the reliability of a path is the product of the weights divided by the maximum weight (10).  This allows `R = 1.0`, let's try it.  Consider the example

> Path A with **Weights[10,10,10]** and Path B with **Weights[1,1]**,
>   Path A is apparently more desirable.

For that example

```
RA = 10/10 * 10/10 * 10/10
RA = 100%

RB = 1/10 * 1/10
RB = 1%
```

RA > RB therefore Path A is more reliable than Path B.

I said that's a 1st approximation, because if you add a third path

> Path C with **Weights[10,10]**

```
RC = 10/10 * 10/10
RC = 100%
```

RA = RC yet we know Path C is more reliable (fewer edges).  Conclusion: `R < 1.0` is a requirement.  Let's add a [fudge factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_factor) to the denominator to make it greater than the maximum weight, 10+1 = 11, this ensures `R < 1.0`.  Now you have

```
RA = 10/11 * 10/11 * 10/11
RA = 75%

RB = 1/11 * 1/11
RB = 0.83%

RC = 10/11 * 10/11
RC = 83%
```

The most reliable is **Path C**, at 83%.

### Side Note

That Wikipedia article points out

> In order to evaluate RBD, closed form solution are available in the
>   case of statistical independence among blocks or components. In the
>   case the statistical independence assumption is not satisfied,
>   specific formalisms and solution tools, such as dynamic RBD, have
>   to be considered.

In other words, that simple formula for series reliability where the total reliability is the product of the individual reliabilities is valid only if there is no correlation between them.

The financial crisis in 2008 was due in part to [an incorrect assumption](http://www.wired.com/2009/02/wp-quant/) that the risk of default of individual mortgages was not highly correlated with other mortgages in other parts of the country... that assumption was wrong, and as they say the rest is history.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The results of this method is rather corresponding to my initial ratings on those paths. If there is any exception I may come up with, I'll let you know :).